# ItemListener itemStateChanged does not change when choosing an index with the same content

Tags: java, jcombobox, itemlistener

For example i have a JComboBox with values : 
**`{"weapon","armor","weapon"}`** 
If currently selected index is 0 `(weapon)` and I select index 2 `(weapon)`, it does not trigger an ItemStateChanged in my ItemListener. Although if currently selected index is 0 and I select index 1, it triggers an ItemStateChanged.

Here is my code as of now:

```
class CBListener implements ItemListener{
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
       JComboBox temp = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
       int wordIndex = temp.getSelectedIndex(); // index of selected string in the list
       int row = sTable.getSelectedRow(); // row of the cell
       int col = sTable.getSelectedColumn(); // column of the cell

       sTable.setValueAt(listE.get(row)[wordIndex], row, 0);
        //System.out.println(listE.get(row)[wordIndex]);
       sTable.setValueAt(listI.get(row)[wordIndex], row, 1);
       sTable.setValueAt(listD.get(row)[wordIndex], row, 3);

    }        
}
```

How can I modify my code so that I can get an index similar to index 2 in my example?

Comment: Before you get too hung up on this, reconsider how you are using JComboBox -- should you really have two entries named exactly the same that have different effects when chosen?

Comment: Yes, the two `weapon` items would mean a different thing. This would indicate that there is an item in the list that is an exact duplicate of another, but both are independent objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would still recommend some differentiation between the two items, but if you really want them to be the same, I think you'll have to create an object that has a toString value of "weapon", but for which an equals returns false. Something like:

```
public BuyableItem( String description, int index ) {
:
:
}

public String toString() {
   return this.description;
}

public boolean equals( BuyableItem item ) {
   boolean retVal = this.description.equals( item.description );
   if( retVal ) {
      retVal = this.index == item.index;
   }
   return retVal;
}
```

Then your JComboBox values could be

```
{ new BuyableItem( "weapon", 0 ), new BuyableItem( "armor", 1 ), new BuyableItem( "weapon", 2 ) };
```